# How can I write a text in GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, textwriter

How can I write text in GLUT and C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing 3D character You can follow this tutorials http://videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/draw_text/home.php

For 2D character You can draw bitmap character here is the example http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com/2011/11/bitmap-is-rectangular-array-of-0s-and.html